# Android Studio in an offline isolated environment

Tags: android, maven, gradle, build

I manage an offline, air gapped, dev environment that supports many different types of coding projects. My most frustrating project to maintain is our Android Studio projects.

Our dev environment is isolated with no access to the internet. When I have to bring a new machine up for a user or bring in updates to the Android SDK it usually involves heartburn with getting the building in sync across multiple systems.

Is there well documented processes for building Android apps manually, somehow forcing the Gradle/maven libraries to point to an easily copied and setup place? I'm thinking C make file like build process. When we ran Eclipse it was easy to spin up a new system, just scp someone else's environment. Is there some alternative to mirroring the Google maven environment internally?

Am I over thinking the Android studio build process?

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle build system needs to download your dependencies and store them. after downloading them, as long as there is no change to the dependency gradle will use it's cached version of it on its own.

Now, as long as your dependency tasks remain UP-TO-DATE (the dependency has not changed) you should be fine without a connection.

You could also manually put the jars and aars of your dependencies and use gradle to use them instead -

Just modify the dependencies to compile your libs dir and not get them online (all those compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0' are just url's of sorts pointing to the location of the files) and place the necessary files in libs

Another way of obtaining the files easily would be to run the project once in a connected environment and getting the necessary jars from .gradle/caches/

Comment: I've copied the .gradle/caches directory in the past, however its been between different versions of android studio which might of ultimately been the issue that still led to android studio getting stuck between wanting to run "offline" but still wanting to connect to download libraries.

Comment: Could be, safest bet in my opinion would be to just delete the dependencies and get them straight from the libs folder...

Answer (score 0):

I have been working in similar conditions. To make development much easier you should setup repository management system. Two popular options are [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) and [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype). In your build tools repository configuration, you should refer to your repository management tool address. With this setup, every computer in the network has to get the source code from version control and good to go.(no extra configuration is required)
In an enviroment with internet connection you can prepare the repository your projects depending and after transfering these files to internal network upload these to your repository management tool.